# Хранение рабочего времени оператора MySql

Tags: mysql

Столкнулся с проблемой. Нужно сделать рабочее время для оператора онлайн ресурса.

Не приходит в голову как это сделать грамотно?

Я вот набросал такое - картинка.

Суть в том что есть три типа режима работы - **Круглосуточно**, **В заданные часы**, **В зависимости от дня недели**.

Подробнее:
**Круглосуточно** - Выбираем только те дни недели при которых оператора будет работать
**В заданные часы** - Выбираем дни недели при которых оператора будет работать, но в ограниченные часы в выбранные дни. К примеру в Понедельник, Среду и Пятницу с 9:00 до 18:00.
**В зависимости от дня недели** - Тут сложнее. Выбираем дни недели при которых оператора будет работать и настраиваем время от-до для каждого дня отдельно.

Как такое отобразить в бд? разные таблицы под каждый тип рабочего времени?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Все 3 типа отлично укладываются в структуру "день недели, от, до". Круглосуточно: день недели, от 00:00, до 23:59. В заданные часы вы все равно выбираете дни недели, так что это частный случай "От дня недели", просто во все дни время работы одинаково. А все различия - только в пользовательском интерфейсе, для удобства ввода

Comment: Мысль понял. Но вот не понял как это отобразить в таблицах. Дней недели то 7. Не буду же я делать 7 столбцов в таблице `operatorWorkTime` под каждый день недели. Там даже не то что каждый день недели. А там получиться boolean активен ли день и след две колонки время от-до. Если день не активен, то и времени нет.

Comment: 4 колонки: 1. Некий id из другой таблицы (я не понял по рисунку к чему оно относится, к workTimeType или скажем к оператору. в общем id из той таблицы). 2. день недели (tinyint, от 1 до 7), 3. время от, 4. время до. Когда надо на несколько дней недели - делаем несколько записей, на каждый из дней. Если день выходной - запись с ним отсутствует

Comment: `id` какой? не понял. То бишь в workTimeType добавить 4 колонки. так?

Comment: @Mike добавил картинку. Я контент других таблиц упростил ибо он не так важен.

Comment: @Mike тип рабочего времени наверно тоже надо добавить. ибо как определить к какому типу относится график.

Comment: В таблице workTime нет собственного id, она же обеспечивает несколько записей для сущности с одним id. Первичный ключ в ней из двух полей id и day. И id этот судя по всему берется из operatorWorkTime

Comment: @Mike все что написано просто id это собственные поля, не связи. Обновил картинку в теме. Я правильно Вас понял? Тип спецом сделал отдельно что бы понять что к какому типу относится. Может тип как-то иначе можно сделать. буду рад, если подскажете

Comment: теперь у вас вышло что у понедельника может быть один тип, а у вторника (для тех же operator, site) другой тип. Если так и планировалось, то ok.

Comment: @Mike точно. не учел. Не планировалось. Может быть только один тип. ААА. в таблице operatorWorkTime сделать поле типа. Все поля касательно дня недели и времени вынести в другую таблицу workType и ту да же добавить связь с operatorWorkTime записью. Так будет норм?

Comment: @Mike обновил картинку

Comment: да. так. просто я не люблю делать собственные id в таких таблицах. они обычно смысла не несут. Хотя если нравится можете конечно оставить. только не забудьте (operatorWorkTimeId, day) сделать уникальным ключем

Comment: @Mike фигня в том что я работаю с бд через Hibernate (Java). а он требует id. Я пытался сделать без id, но он валится и кричит что ему нужен id. так что там. а чего уникальным то? Допустим, мы выбрали тип какой-то. тип записался в таблицу operatorWorkTime, а все детали типа (дни недели, время т.д.) по одной записи на каждый день пойдут в таблицу workTime. А значит что запись в operatorWotkTime будет одна, а в workTime только те что были выбраны. А если поставить уникальность, то больше одной записи я не запишу. Зачем делать уникальность?

Comment: Уникальный ключ состоящий из двух полей (operatorWorkTimeId, day), обеспечивает уникальность именно связки. А без него у вас будет семь пятниц на неделе, потому что можно будет внести две и более пятниц для одного и того же operatorWorkTimeId

Comment: @Mike А. Хм. как это сделать?) просто отметить поле как `unique`?

Comment: @Mike Создайте ответ. я отмечу как решение.